# How to calculate the exp-like series with reciprocal square coefficients?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am trying to calculate a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(a+1+n)^2} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$ for $a \in [0, 100]$ and $x \in [0,150]$. I know that it is related to generalized hypergeometric $_2F_2(a+1,a+1;a+2,a+2;-x)$. But I don't want to use the complicated $_2F_2()$. Any suggestions on how to approximately calculate this series? Such as asymptotes with simple functions like $\exp(),\log(), \Gamma()$, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{1}{(a+1+n)^2} = \int_{0}^{1}- z^{n+a}\log(z)\,dz$ the whole series can be represented as

$$ \int_{0}^{1}-z^a \log(z) \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-xz)^n}{n!}\,dz = \int_{0}^{1}-z^a \log(z) e^{-xz}\,dz=\frac{1}{x^{a+1}}\int_{0}^{x}-u^a e^{-u}\log\frac{u}{a}\,du $$
and computed through the incomplete $\Gamma$ function and its derivative, having manageable representations as [generalized continued fractions](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/10/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, I found myself circle back to generalized hypergeometric 2F2 again, and its generalized continued fraction seems not precise enough.

Comment: @EliCong: may I ask about the original problem requiring such evaluation/approximation?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the derivative of $_1 F_1(1, a+1, x)$ wrt parameter $a$.

Comment: @EliCong: one step back again: why is it important to you to compute/approximate $$\frac{d}{da}\phantom{}_1 F_1(1;a+1;x) $$ ?

Comment: Actually, what I need is the derivative of Gamma distribution' CDF wrt the Gamma shape parameter. Practically, I want to efficiently calculate that derivative, such as using asympotote.